# How to rename network printer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

This question is similar to [How do you rename a printer device in Windows 7 64 bit](https://superuser.com/questions/214323/how-do-you-rename-a-printer-device-in-windows-7-64-bit), except the answers there do not work, and I'll provide more information.

This is a home network, not a domain.  I have set up a Brother HL-5170DN.  It is a network printer connected directly to an Ethernet hub.  I can connect to  it with Windows 7, but on Windows 7 it defaults to the name "binary_p1 on Brn37415f", which isn't very useful.  And I cannot seem to change the name.

I have it working with several Windows XP and Vista machines, and I can change the name on those machines.

On Windows 7 **Printer properties**:

- I can see the "binary_p1" name on the **General** tab.  I can select the text, but I cannot change it.  The field is not grayed out, but I cannot type anything into it.
- On the **Ports** tab, all of the controls are grayed out (disabled).  The selected Port is called "\\Brn_37415f\binary_p1", and it's described as "Client Side Rendering Provider" and the printer field says "binary_p1".
- On the **Security** tab, I can see that my account has "Manage this printer" permissions.

If I choose **Printer Server Properties**, I can select the port and click **Configure Port**, but I get a dialog that says, "An error occurred during port configuration.  This option is not supported."

I have found many forums with people asking the same question without getting an answer.

**Update:** No more bounties to offer, but I'm still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: How did you add this printer? did you add it as network or local? If network try adding it as a local printer and when you get to ports create a new port, select tcp/ip, and put in the IP of the printer... You can then name it whatever you want...

Comment: What is the device make/model the printer is shared from?

Comment: @Kyle:  I added the printer as a network printer.  The printer relies on DHCP, so the IP address changes from time to time.  I haven't found a way to give it a fixed IP address with my Netgear router.  I used to be able to do that with my old Linksys.

Comment: @edusysadmin:  I'm not sure I understand your question.  The printer (Brother HL-5170DN) has a built-in print server.  I just connect the Ethernet port to my router.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/home-network-printer-setup-that-works/

Answer (score 10):

Here's the way to do this on Windows 7 and 8.1 for non-IP based printers:

1. Add a printer
2. Add a local printer (not network)
3. Create a new port (local port, not TCP/IP)
4. Fill in portname (\server\printer syntax)

Follow the rest of the steps (you likely will have to manually pick the printer driver, you can find this easily if you already mapped the network printer by viewing its properties).

This will let you do this.

Comment: I'm unclear on step 4.  What am I supposed to put for the server name?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy in your post it looks like `\Brn_37415f\binary_p1` though this is old enough I do not actually remember off hand. Presumably adding it as a regular network printer will let you see this however as you can inspect the printer to see what its server address is.

Comment: I think `\server\printer` should be `\\server\printer`.

Answer (score 6):

I just did it on my Windows 7 installation.

Go to *Device and Printers*, right click on the printer you want to change, select "Printer Properties", not properties or printing preferences. Change the name in the top box. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> when done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my case, the text in the top box is not editable.  I can select it, but I cannot change it.  You example is not a network printer.  I think that's a key difference.

Comment: Try a switch instead of a hub, might make a difference.

Comment: I misspoke.  It is a switch, not a hub.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Both the right-click > Rename and File > Rename were disabled, but the text box in the Properties window was editable. Also, my printer is a network printer, not local.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

1. Stop the print service
   `net stop spooler`
2. locate the printer in the registry under
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\$device`
   Network printers usually have a key which starts with to commas, like
   `,,http://example.com:555,nameofprinter`
3. Be `$new` the desired name of the printer. Change:
   value of "Name" in `$device` to `$new`
   value of "printerName" in `$device\DsSpooler` to `$new`
   value of "uNCName" in `$device\DsSpooler` to `\\$computername\\\$new`
   finally rename the printers registry key from `$device` to `$new`
4. restart printer service:
   `net start spooler`

---

Info gathered from
http://sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/89521-rename-network-printer.htm
http://virtualroadside.com/blog/index.php/2007/10/17/prnrename-an-autoit-based-utility-to-rename-ipp-printers-in-windows/

Comment: This one looked the most promising, however when I attempted to try it, the registry key 'Print' was not in 'CurrentVersion', also tried the WOW6432Node branch.

Comment: This one worked for me in windows 10 as well.

Comment: The default name of my IPP printer was "gateway-usb-printer" on Windows 7, I couldn't change it using the windows UI. The solution based on "PRNCNFG.vbs" didn't work either, it failed with the error 0x80041002  (not found). The modification of the registry as described in this answer is the only thing that worked.

Comment: This solution worked for me, when the simple methods like editing the name directly under Printer Properties did not work.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot rename a network printer in Windows XP, Vista or 7 (not sure about others). The only way to rename is to rename it on the server, but this will break existing configuration.

There is a workaround though: you can map a LPT port to a network printer and then install as a local printer.

To map a LPT port use the following command on an command prompt with administrator privileges:

```
net use lptX \\Brn_37415f\binary_p1 /persistent:yes
```

Replace the "X" with the LPT port you want to use, for example 2 (if your mainboard has no LPT port you can use 1 too).

Then just install the printer as if it was a local printer attached to the LPT port you specified

Comment: Actually, I can rename the printer on XP and Vista.  Just not Windows 7.  There is no distinct print server per se.  The server is built directly into the printer.

Comment: The net use command worked, and I was able to install the printer as a local printer on LPT1.  Unfortunately, printing to it gets a generic "Error - Printing" status in the queue and nothing prints.

Comment: Did you use the correct drivers? Sometimes there are different network and local drivers. Also, can you print from the command line to the port? (google it)

Also if your printer is a direct network printer @Kyle's solution might work

Comment: I believe I'm using the right drivers.  I tried the ones from the manufacturer's disk and then I uninstalled those and tried the ones from Microsoft update (exact match on model number).  Trying to print from the command line get the same "Error - Printing" status in the queue.

Comment: Awarding bounty to the highest voted response because it's out of time.  Unfortunately, I still don't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After testing both, I found this to be correct:

You need to add the printer as a local printer in order to change the name, otherwise Windows defaults it to the share name.

When you add the printer select local. Then select create port and specify TCP/IP:

[image]

Then put in your printer's IP address:

[image]

Then just follow the wizard as you would with any other local printer installation.

Comment: This will only work on a pure network printer though, not on a printer shared through a windows PC.

Comment: @dtech "I have set up a Brother HL-5170DN. It is a network printer connected directly to an Ethernet hub." sounds like a network printer to me...

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the printer gets its IP address from DHCP, so it changes from time to time.  I've tried setting the router to always serve it the same IP address, but that's not possible with my Netgear access point (it was with my old Linksys).

Comment: @adrian you can do it with any router..... just lower the dhcp pool: say it gives 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 just lower it to 192.168.1.250 and manually set the IP on the device. honestly you don't even need to involve the router if you are not worried about having 250+ devices on your network.

Comment: @kyle: As far as I can tell, there is no way to manually set the IP address for the printer.  It appears to be hardcoded to rely on DHCP.

Comment: @Adrian find it's current IP address and log into the web Interface...

Comment: @Kyle:  There is no web interface.  Brother provides a tool for an SNMP interface, but it won't install on Windows 7.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy what if, instead of the IP address, you put the printer's network hostname into `Hostname or IP address` and then put the desired "friendly" name into `Port name`?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the VERY same issue, but I might also add to what's already been discussed...

If I connect to a shared printer on my domain (the PC is attached to a workstation, NOT the server) I do NOT get the printer installed on my workstation as the shared name...

The share is called HCFA, and appears as such in the network browser.

When I double click it, the driver will download and install, but the printer is named on MY computer as "HP LaserJet 1320 on XXXX", and I cannot rename it locally, or it breaks the share to all the OTHER computers that are connected to this same printer, EVEN IF I rename it locally to the very same name as the remote share already has.

The workstation is a DHCP client, but it has a reservation in the scope for itself.  I had to do this when one of the XP workstaions in my organization stomped on it's IP, and DNS lost that workstation.  I can now browse TO the workstation, and see and connect to its shares, but I cannot rename them.

I suppose I COULD just add a 170x to the network...  I'd really like to know why I can't use this the SAME way I would have setup an XP shared printer.  < mumble > I hate Windows 7... < /mumble >

Comment: I'd be thrilled if it would show the model as the name of the printer.  Mine it much more cryptic.

Answer (score -1):

If you like, rename the printer on the network:

1. Right-clicking printer properties, then clear text and type like name
2. For computer network, RUN > `\\computer_name` to connect to the printer
   and double click.

Comment: As I said in the question, the name in on the printer properties page is not editable.