# How to change name showing up in print dialog for a shared printer

Tags: windows-8.1, network-printer, homegroup

I recently added a shared printer to my system. Sharing is accomplished via my Homegroup in Windows 8. When I look at the printer in the Devices and Printers, the printer name shows up as "Samsung SCX-4623 on my-server". But, when I go to actually print something in an application (such as Acrobat), the printer name shows up as "\my-server\Samsung SCX-4623". Is there some way that I can change how the printer name shows up in applications so that I don't have the UNC path at the beginning, similar to how the printer shows up in Devices and Printers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/552258/471071). You need to create a local printer with a port using the UNC name.