# How to rename http network printer name on Windows 10?

Tags: printer, cups

I have USB printer shared using [CUPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) on Linux machine.
I have installed this printer on my Windows 10
[win10_printer_installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTKIo.png)
Now when I want to print anything there is ugly long printer name which I can't not change. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the way how to change the printer name. It is described here:
https://superuser.com/a/803260/1001256